# Convert array of mixed type elements to title-cased string

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, implode, title-case

I have an array containing integers and letters and I need to remove the integers and form a string which is all lowercase except the first letter.

```
$chars = ["A", 1, 2, "h", "m", "E", "D"];

//Needed Output is: Ahmed
```

My attempt:

```
foreach ($chars as $char) {
  if (gettype($char) == "string") {
    echo strtolower($char);
  }
}
```

```
The Output is:

ahmed
```

but I don't how to make the first letter Capital, Is there any function that can do that with arrays?

Comment: _"Is there any function can do that with arrays?"_ - why with arrays? `$char` is not an array.

Comment: So do I need function deals with strings to do that?

Comment: Because I tried to make it with ucfirst() but it didn't work it gave me AHMED and I want Ahmed.

Comment: Well you need to apply it to the _first_ character only, not all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - there is an [ucfirst](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) function, but it only works on **string** not **arrays**

So we need to prepare a little bit. You can use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to convert the array and glue it with an empty seperator.

**ucfirst** will convert only the first letter to Capital, so we need to make sure that the other letters are lowercase; we can use [strtolower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function to achieve that.

And finally - I would use an [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for that foreach in your code

```php
function testChar($char) {
    return gettype($char) === "string";
}

$chars = ["A", 1, 2, "h", "m", "E", "D"];
$result = array_filter($chars, "testChar");
$stringResult = implode("", $result);
$toLowerstringResult = strtolower($stringResult);
$ucfirstResult = ucfirst($toLowerstringResult);
echo $ucfirstResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Filter out non-string type elements.
2. Convert the array to a string.
3. Force all letters to lowercase except the first which must be uppercase.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KJ1Lo))

```
echo mb_convert_case(
         implode(
             array_filter(
                 $chars,
                 'is_string'
             )
         ),
         MB_CASE_TITLE
     );
```